# MySQL large number of opened tables -- we're noticing performance hits

Tags: mysql

We have 3 database servers, containing 200, 200 and 146 databases respectively. Each database contains about 250 tables. These definitions are the same for 99% of the databases - dependent on the version of software each customer is running on. We've been running this since over a week, and performance was great. It's dropping now, and we're not sure where to look.

Output from the first SQL:

```
> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'open_%'
>   -> +--------------------------+----------+
    -> | Variable_name            | Value    |
    -> +--------------------------+----------+
    -> | Open_files               | 1        |
    -> | Open_streams             | 0        |
    -> | Open_table_definitions   | 633      |
    -> | Open_tables              | 400      |
    -> | Opened_files             | 5078508  |
    -> | Opened_table_definitions | 1905982  |
    -> | Opened_tables            | 8910560  |
    -> +--------------------------+----------+
```

`show variables` output: https://gist.github.com/Ma-ve/453c80de33cb55064bd1dcb142fa83c4

Server has 16 GB of RAM, 8 vCPU. Any other specs can be requested.

edit: Full output from `SHOW STATUS;` as of a few minutes ago: https://gist.github.com/Ma-ve/ecc8ac4e67965d5da4f5de0a58436263#file-status-log-L3

Full output from `SHOW VARIABLES;` as of a few minutes ago: https://gist.github.com/Ma-ve/d0ba67695ef6d5b1a2020648250ded89

Server details:

- 16 GB RAM, a DigitalOcean Droplet (regular droplet)
- 120 GB disk
- Output `du -sh /var/lib/mysql`: `19G`
- Output `uptime`: `11:26:46 up 270 days, 23:37,  3 users,  load average: 1.20, 1.39, 1.49`
- `vm.swappiness = 0`

Bit of history behind the query cache: we had it disabled when we had only 15 clients on a server, and performance was godawful. Enabling it (as it was enabled on our old server) instantly solved a lot of performance issues.

Comment: It is 3 servers, each containing up to 200 databases. Each database contains roughly 250 tables. The stats I posted are from 1 server, `sql-01`.

Comment: To be safer, set swappiness to 1.

Comment: @mave  Would you expect any negative results if you limited SELECT ... to 1M rows?   Do you ever expect this kind of row volume in delivering data to your users?  Would you consider using in your my.cnf/ini sql_select_limit = 1M  to avoid 'runaway' SELECT attempt?

Answer (score 3):

`Opened_tables` (etc) is useless without dividing by `Uptime`.  I recommend no more than 2/sec.  Perhaps 1/sec for `Opened_table_definitions/Uptime`.  Those are under the control of these:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| table_definition_cache     | 1500  |
| table_open_cache           | 1555  |
| table_open_cache_instances | 4     |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

And rethink the wisdom of having so many databases and so many tables.

`open_files_limit` and the OS limit are also involved.

`Table_open_cache_hits` and `Table_open_cache_misses` and `Table_open_cache_overflows` are useful to watch.  Up to 1 miss or overflow/sec might be a good goal.

When increasing cache(s), be sure not to use up so much RAM that swapping occurs.  If swapping does occur, the quick fix is to decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size` a little.

If you would like more analysis, please provide the info requested [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning) .

**Tuning Analysis**

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 21d 01:09:23
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Really bad:  `query_cache_size` should not be more than about 50M.  2GB leads to a lot of overhead in purging entries.  Consider turning off the QC.

Since MyISAM is not used much, decrease `key_buffer_size` to `50M`.

`open_file_limit` is only 1024.  This is probably because Ubuntu is restricting 
it to 1024 -- see ulimit, and raise it.  After that, increase `table_open_cache` to
at least 5K, and a few others.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` (10G) is probably at a good size.  I deduce that you have less than tha much data.

`innodb_log_file_size` is quite high for the amount of activity you have.
But it is not important to change it.

Why is `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (and similar things) being run so many times?

Why so many `ALTER TABLEs`?

It seems that a lot of `SELECTs` are inefficient.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) for what to do next.

`LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES` should rarely, if ever, be used with InnoDB.  What is going on?

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size - 1.2 * Key_blocks_used * 1024) / _ram ) = (512M - 1.2 * 32 * 1024) / 16384M = 3.1%` -- Percent of RAM wasted in key_buffer.
-- Decrease key_buffer_size.

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 32 * 1024 / 512M = 0.01%` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( Opened_tables ) = 10,163,367 / 1818563 = 5.6 /sec` -- Frequency of opening Tables
-- increase table_open_cache

`( Opened_table_definitions ) = 2,479,464 / 1818563 = 1.4 /sec` -- Frequency of opening .frm files
-- Increase table_definition_cache and/or table_open_cache.

`( open_files_limit ) = 1,024` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

`( Table_open_cache_overflows ) = 10,109,150 / 1818563 = 5.6 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache

`( Table_open_cache_misses ) = 10,163,360 / 1818563 = 5.6 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 132,895 / 655280 = 20.3%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size to bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 10,751,949,312 / (1818563 / 3600) / 2 / 256M = 0.0396` -- Ratio 
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 1,818,563 / 60 * 256M / 10751949312 = 756` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size. (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (1137006 + 1592424) / 249138897 = 1.1%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( query_cache_size ) = 2048M` -- Size of QC
-- Too small = not of much use. Too large = too much overhead. Recommend either 0 or no more than 50M.

`( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (2048M - 1143770840) / 560588 / 8192 = 0.219` -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 2,468,770 / 1818563 = 1.4 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size. 
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / (Created_tmp_disk_tables + Created_tmp_tables) ) = 2,468,770 / (2468770 + 4016418) = 38.1%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- maybe increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size; avoid blobs, etc.

`( Com_rollback / Com_commit ) = 2,444 / 8577 = 28.5%` -- Rollback : Commit ratio
-- Rollbacks are costly; change app logic

`( Select_scan ) = 5,519,376 / 1818563 = 3 /sec` -- full table scans 
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 5,519,376 / 21974063 = 25.1%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Com_alter_table ) = 85,985 / 1818563 = 0.047 /sec`
-- Why so many ALTERs?

`( back_log / max_connections ) = 92 / 214 = 43.0%`

`( Connections ) = 10,172,085 / 1818563 = 5.6 /sec` -- Connections 
-- Increase wait_timeout; use pooling?

`( thread_cache_size ) = 100` -- How many extra processes to keep around (Not relevant when using thread pooling) (Autosized as of 5.6.8; based on max_connections)
-- 0 is good for Windows
0 is inefficient for non-Windows; 10 is probably fine

`( thread_cache_size / max_connections ) = 100 / 214 = 46.7%`

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_create_db = 0.35 /HR
Com_create_table = 85 /HR
Com_create_trigger = 19 /HR
Com_create_user = 0.34 /HR
Com_drop_table = 85 /HR
Com_drop_user = 0.014 /HR
Com_grant = 0.34 /HR
Com_release_savepoint = 3.6 /HR
Com_rollback_to_savepoint = 0.25 /sec
Com_savepoint = 3.6 /HR
Com_show_create_db = 3.6 /HR
Com_show_create_func = 0.96 /HR
Com_show_create_table = 0.63 /sec
Com_show_create_trigger = 0.054 /sec
Com_show_events = 3.6 /HR
Com_show_fields = 0.88 /sec
Com_show_function_status = 3.6 /HR
Com_show_privileges = 0.002 /HR
Com_show_procedure_status = 3.6 /HR
Com_show_table_status = 0.25 /sec
Com_show_triggers = 0.25 /sec
Com_unlock_tables = 89 /HR
Handler_savepoint = 3.6 /HR
Handler_savepoint_rollback = 0.25 /sec
Performance_schema_digest_lost = 2.56e+7
Qcache_free_blocks = 342,300
Qcache_free_memory = 1.14e+9
Qcache_total_blocks = 1.49e+6
Select_full_range_join = 55,471
Threads_cached = 93
eq_range_index_dive_limit = 200
group_concat_max_len = 1.0e+6
innodb_purge_threads = 4
performance_schema_max_file_classes = 80
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes = 210
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 193
query_cache_limit = 1.05e+8
```

**Abnormal string values:**

```
innodb_force_load_corrupted = OFF
innodb_undo_directory = ./
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
slave_rows_search_algorithms = TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
```

Comment: Hi Rick -- apologies for the delay in response, and missing key information. I've updated the OP with the information to boot

Answer (score 0):

How long has this configuration been running?  If it is something you setup some time ago, what is new or different? Look there first.

If this is a new setup, then I'd suggest you start with:

A.  Any errors in the DB logs?

B.  What errors do you see in the system logs?

If you see errors there, then correct those first.

C.  What about your network logs, any errors there?

If no errors, or all errors are fixed and the problem continues:

A. Run an analysis tool like Ubiq or what you normally use on your database(s); look for buffer problems, cache problems, locking issues. 
Fix any issues shown by the analysis.

Question: did you have this configuration of hardware & databases at least reviewed by your vendor, or an experienced DB architect? 2 CPU's, 16 Gb RAM, and I hope enough swap space just in case.  I ask this because you are putting many databases on 1 server. Even if they are all separate instances, it's still a lot of processing on 1 box.  Make sure you have the horsepower to run it all.

Comment: We were on Rackspace's Cloud DB instance before this, running well over 1200 databases on a single instance. That didn't perform great, but it was consistent. This new architecture is great in the early mornings/late evenings, but inconsistent during the day.

Answer (score 0):

'inconsistent during the day' Mave Nov 14 at 20:30

my.cnf things to do:

```
in [mysqld] section, 

max_heap_table_size = 24M # from 16M
tmp_table_size = 24M # from 16M  to reduce 38% HDD used today
innodb_io_capacity = 2000 # from 200 for additional capacity
innodb_io_capacity = 20000 # from 2000 for additional capacity
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128K # from 256K to reduce 4738 RPS
delay_key_write = OFF # from ON to speed storage and minimize corruption exposure
key_buffer_size = 100K # from 500+ M, used only by MyISAM
innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 10 # from 25%, less than 3% max used in 20 days
innodb_read_ahead_threshold = 8 # from 56 rather than waiting
innodb_stats_sample_pages = 32 # from 8 to improve cardinality data for optimizer
max_seeks_for_key = 64 # from a huge number to limit wasted dives
max_write_lock_count = 5 # from a huge number to give RD a chance quicker
query_cache_limit = 1M # from ~ 104K for EACH QC candidate size limit 
query_cache_min_res_unit = 512 # from 4096 to pack more QC results into QC
query_prealloc_size = 32K # from 8K to avoid acquiring RAM all day for parsing
```

Typical HARD rules, only one a day and be sure before moving to next attempt to smooth your performance.

Problems to be addressed related to the 20 days of status information, 
A. why 446,000 com_rollback_to savepoints ?
B. why 2,444 com_rollback ?
C. normally Com_begin has a companion Com_commit.  4,283 short on commit.
D. 196 com_flush    side effect is destruction of much of Query Cache results
E. Failure to have innodb_print_all_deadlocks = ON means you will never know what caused the problem or figure it out.
F. ~ 5 million select_scan usually means an index is missing that could speed process
G. only 1 of each 7 candidate query results made it into Query Cache.  One minute of your general log will enable analysis to determine if this ratio could be improved significantly.
H. Handler_write high count implies you are storing new data most of the time.

Hoping you are making progress on raising ulimit capacity within Linux.  This will allow more 'hits' than current ulimit's.

So much of your effort has been EXCELLENT and these suggestions in no way are critical of where you are today.  Need your feedback, when time permits.  Not every DAY.

Comment: @mave  Any progress with enhancing your server's performance?  Please let us know, good or bad.  Thanks